# Last imageView tapped UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I use the following code to add about 29 image to `UIScrollView`.

```
- (void)setupHorizontalScrollView
{
 _scrollViewEffects.delegate = self;

[_scrollViewEffects setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

_scrollViewEffects.clipsToBounds = NO;
_scrollViewEffects.scrollEnabled = YES;
_scrollViewEffects.pagingEnabled = YES;

NSUInteger nimages = 0;
NSInteger tot=0;
CGFloat cx = 0;
for (; ; nimages++) {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"e%d.png", nimages];
    UIImage *imageThumb = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    [imageView setTag:nimages];

    if (tot==29) {
        break;
    }
    if (4==nimages) {
        nimages=0;
    }

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageThumb];



    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = 50;
    rect.size.width = 50;
    rect.origin.x = cx;
    rect.origin.y = 0;
    imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    imageView.frame = rect;

    [_scrollViewEffects addSubview:imageView];

    cx += imageView.frame.size.width+5;
    tot++;

}

//self.pageControl.numberOfPages = nimages;

[_scrollViewEffects setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [_scrollViewEffects bounds].size.height)];

[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];



}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"image tapped!!!");
}
```

As you can see, UserInteraction is Enabled, everything works, But the code detects taps only for Last image from UIScrollView. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

to be inside the loop.  You're setting user interaction enabled on only the last image, after the loop is complete.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks a lot. Can you tell me please how can I check which image was touched? As you saw on my code, I tried to add tags to each image inside the loop, but I have no idea how to check. I tried: if (imageView.tag == 1) { NSLog(@"tag 1") but doesnt work

Comment: When the handleSingleTap: fires, the gesture recognizer is passed at the param.  The gesture recognizer has a view property, which is the view to which it was attached.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating only 1 instance of the imageView. To fix your problem you have to create a new instance for eatch imageView:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    UIIMageVIew *imgView = [[UIIMageView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

This will create 5 `UIIMageView` instances.

The difference here is that a new instance is added 5 times and in your code atm is adding the same instance so when you add them they will not "exist" and only the last one will.

And to improve your for loop set it up like I did here but put 29 instead, it'll make your code cleaner and shorter.

Comment: What makes you say the OP is creating only 1 instance of imageView?  The code has quite a few problems, but that isn't one of them.  The alloc is inside the loop.

Comment: He has a global imageView and I thought It wouldnt create a new instance because of that.